# How to correctly write a javascript code that change the text of a div via onClick event

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and I am writing a simple site, I having a problem changing the content of a div when user click any of the menu link. So far I've tried the following code below:

When user click the menu the div text content will change. For example when user click the **NEWS menu**  `"<div class="paneltitle" id="contenttitle">Home</div>"` should change the content from **HOME** to **NEWS**

**HTML**

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="menu">

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_home()">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_news()">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_contact()">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_about()">About</a></li>
</ul>   
        </div>


        <div class="body_content">
            <div class="paneltitle" id="contenttitle">Home</div>
        </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
    float: left;
}

.body_content {
    float: left;
    height: 380px;
    background: red;
    width: 620px
}

.paneltitle {
    background: gray;
    width: 98.5%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**JS**

```
function changetitle_home() {
document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Home";
}

function changetitle_news() {
document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "News";
}

function changetitle_contact() {
document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Contact";
}

function changetitle_about() {
document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "About Us";
}
```

Check my JSfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/453j50uL/1/

Comment: Does it also happen on server? If it fails in jsfiddle, it's because you're calling the javascript code in an onload function, which makes your code nested and therefore inaccessible for html property `onclick` If you set jsfiddle option to `no-wrap in body` it will work.

Comment: @kaiido damn you are correct. I just tried it now it works. thanks dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted works just fine when combined into a page and loaded in a browser. Copy and save the following code as a HTML file and load it in a browser. I've stripped out the CSS for clarity but feel free to put it back in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changetitle_home() {
            document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Home";
        }
        function changetitle_news() {
            document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "News";
        }
        function changetitle_contact() {
            document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Contact";
        }
        function changetitle_about() {
            document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "About Us";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_home()">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_news()">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_contact()">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_about()">About</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>

        <div class="body_content">
            <div class="paneltitle" id="contenttitle">Home</div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A better way to do this would be to have a single re-usable function for setting the title, for example:

```
function setPageTitle(title) {
    document.getElementById('contenttitle').innerHTML = title;
}
```

Now, in your function call, pass the desired title as a parameter:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:setPageTitle('Home');">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your JSFiddle you should change Frameworks & Extensions option under jQuery 1.10.1 to `No wrap - in <body>`.
It should works now!

Comment: same with its really working I just dont about "No wrap" in jsfiddle @kaiido

Answer (score 1):

I dont have enough reputation to comment so it is in the answer block. Just copy your functions in a script block and paste it above the . I tried and it works.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
    <div class="menu">
        <script>    function changetitle_home() {
    document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Home";
}
function changetitle_news() {
    document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "News";
}
function changetitle_contact() {
    document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Contact";
}
function changetitle_about() {
    document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "About Us";
}
        </script>            
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_home()">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_news()">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_contact()">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" onclick="changetitle_about()">About</a></li>
</ul>   
    </div>


    <div class="body_content">
        <div class="paneltitle" id="contenttitle">Home</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code having no problem and it should works. The script placement in the fiddle only cause the problem.

I have moved the scripts inside the HTML content, now it works fine as you expected.

Check this Fiddle: [**`Demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/453j50uL/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the way you are defining your functions. If you define them as below they will be hang off the window object so you will be able to reference them from your html. Please take a look at the following jsfiddle for a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/3o3rk889/1/

```
changetitle_home = function() {
        document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Home";
}
changetitle_news = function(){ 
    document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "News";
}
changetitle_contact = function() {
    document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Contact";
}
changetitle_about = function() {
    document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "About Us";
}
```

The way you are defining them leaves them with no handle. Also, top tip: you can use the Dev tools with fiddler (F12 in chrome or IE) and that will show you any errors in the javascript. Doing this showed an undefined error when for those functions when clicking a button.

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOjNRw

I know this has already been answered, but for the sake of writing nice javascript and keeping your HTML clean (not using `onclick`) Here is how I would do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var contentTitle = document.getElementById("contenttitle");
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("#navigation a");

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link){
      link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        contentTitle.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
      }, false);
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul id="navigation">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>

        <div class="body_content">
            <div class="paneltitle" id="contenttitle">Home</div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AlexNewbie woops, i left the `class` on the `ul`, it should be an `id` notice that the second line of javascript is looking for `#navigation a`, not `.navigation a`. I left a codepen so you can try it out.

Comment: nice one, i think this is much better. thanks @AllTheTime

Answer (score 0):

For all links you could use a unique function that looks like this one:

```
var changeTitle = function(target){
   document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
};
```

Your HTML for you menu will look like

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeTitle(this)">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeTitle(this)">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeTitle(this)">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeTitle(this)">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another alternative is definitely using jQuery:

```
$('div.menu a').click(function(e){
    $('#contenttitle').text($(e.target).text());
});
```

Comment: I dont really understand how ur code works. please give example @leo.fcx

Comment: Just improved my response by adding the HTML code change. Also provided another alternative by using jQuery.

Comment: i like you idea, but I dunno how to use it on my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/453j50uL/     @leo.fcx

Answer (score 0):

Just change your script from

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    function changetitle_home() {
        document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Home";
    }
    function changetitle_news() {
        document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "News";
    }
    function changetitle_contact() {
        document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Contact";
    }
    function changetitle_about() {
        document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "About Us";
    }

});//]]>  

</script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 

    function changetitle_home() {
        document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Home";
    }
    function changetitle_news() {
        document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "News";
    }
    function changetitle_contact() {
        document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "Contact";
    }
    function changetitle_about() {
        document.getElementById("contenttitle").innerHTML = "About Us";
    }

//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

see my example code then you understand how javascript onclick event occurred .

[**SEE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tapos00/jf9nrr4y/)

```
<ul>
    <li class="abc" data-id="abc1">Home</li>
    <li class="abc" data-id="abc2">about</li>
    <li class="abc" data-id="abc3">serive</li>
    <li class="abc" data-id="abc4">contact</li>
</ul>
<div class="mm" id="abc1">Home worlld</div>
<div class="mm" id="abc2">about worlld</div>
<div class="mm" id="abc3">Service worlld</div>
<div class="mm" id="abc4">Contact worlld</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mm").hide();
    $("#abc1").show();
    $(".abc").click(function(){
          var mm = $(this).data("id");
            $(".mm").hide();
            $("#"+mm).show();
      });
});
```

Comment: how to show a default title, for example on page load the Home Worlld will show.

Comment: now see this it by defaullt show the home menu description

Comment: yeah, nice @taposghosh